# I want to send an attachment via gmail, choosing the file using an open dialog module

Tags: python, email, tkinter, gmail, attachment

***The code below shows part of my code and I want to use an open dialog module to select the file I would want to attach to my email. I am getting the following error:**

**Cannot attach additional subparts to non-multipart/**

**Please Assist me. I am using a button to open the dialog module thats why I created the function attach. I Have also attched a picture of my GUI application. Thank you**[image]
or","Please Enter The Correct Details!!!")

```
def attachment():
    global file
    file =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    print (file)

def mail():
    try:
        if send_email.get()=="" or send_pass.get()=="" or recv_email.get()=="":
            messagebox.showerror("Error","Please Enter The Complete Details.")
        else:
            a=send_email.get()
            b=send_pass.get()
            c=msg_body.get('1.0',END)
            d=recv_email.get()
            subj = sub_email.get()

            fromx = a
            to  = d
            msg = MIMEText(c)
            msg['Subject'] = subj
            msg['From'] = fromx
            msg['To'] = to


            # Setup the attachment
            filename = os.path.basename(file)
            attachment = open(file, "rb")
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(attachment.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

            # Attach the attachment to the MIMEMultipart object
            msg.attach(part)

            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(a, b)
            server.sendmail(fromx, to, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
            msg_box()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        a=messagebox.askokcancel("Errror","Please Enter The Correct Details!!!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [attach file like object to email python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043215/attach-file-like-object-to-email-python-3)

Comment: No I dont want to put the file location in the code I want to choose it using an open dialog module

Comment: Should `MIMEMultipart` be used instead of `MIMEText`?

Comment: acw1668 please assist me on that one